# Jenkins "Create User" fails on Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: jenkins, administration, webusercontrol

**Short Summary:** The "Create User" form in Jenkins does nothing.

NOTE: I checked other posts related to creating and administering users and saw nothing that clearly describes or solves this problem.

OS = Mac Powerbook OS X 10.13.3 (High Sierra).

First, I installed Oracle Java JDK 8, as specified on the Jenkins installation page.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Then, I installed Jenkins, as specified on the Jenkins installation page. (I installed it on localhost/8081, according to directions, because 8080 was already in use.)

Following the directions, it takes me to a screen for "*Create First Admin User*", as follows...

[image: Jenkins Create New Admin User Page]

I entered data to create a new administrative account and selected the "*Save and Continue*" button.  **NOTHING HAPPENED**.  In other words, hitting the button did nothing and kept me on that page.

To get past it, I simply hit the "*Continue as admin*" button.  This allowed me to continue the installation successfully.

After the installation was complete, I went to the "Create User" page with the intent of creating new users.

[image: Jenkins Create User Page]

I entered the new user information and, again, **NOTHING HAPPENED**.  No matter how many times I enter user data (or different user data), nothing happens.

I also shut down Jenkins and relaunched it but nothing happens.

Maybe I'm wrong but it seems that the "*Create User*" problem is somehow related to the "*Create First Admin User*" issue.

**MY QUESTION:** How would I fix this issue in Jenkins on Mac OS X High Sierra so that I can create, both, new administrative and general users?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in your [Jenkins logs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging#Logging-MacOSX)? It sounds like something might not be set up correctly, but it's not easy to tell without an error message.

Comment: I'm new to Jenkins so I don't know what you mean by "Jenkins logs".  I checked the terminal shell from where I launched Jenkins and saw "INFO: Cannot listen to UDP port 33,848, skipping: java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address
Sep 18, 2018 10:32:39 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running".

Comment: Did you check the link I provided? For a default install on MacOS your Jenkins log file should be located here: `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`

Comment: Just saw the link.  I found two things: 1... Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping; 2... (see above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** This took forever to figure out because there are no error messages or even events in any of the logs.  It turns out that **when you create the new user, in addition to providing Username, Password, and Full Name, you absolutely MUST provide a full E-mail address "x@y.z"**.  It appears that it doesn't even have to be a real E-mail address (although I would advise against providing a fake E-mail address).  If you do not provide an E-mail address, hitting the "Create User" button does absolutely nothing, making it difficult to understand what went wrong.  The screen does not change, at all.  You get no dialog warnings or errors.  You get no info in any logs (Jenkins or System), which is what made debugging this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't be You use non alphanumeric/underscore/dash symbols in newly created username?

I have one **Jenkins ver. 2.147** installation where I had problem exactly as You described it in second step. BTW, users created in same installation before upgrade to this version contains "." in username without problems.

Found this during investigation - enabled self registration, tried to create user with "." and got error message. Same error message does not appear in management dialog screen shown above

Comment: I am using Jenkins v2.151. In this version also, this bug is present. When we try to create a user with a `.` in the username, it silently fails without any error message.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem on my mac. 
I solved it, after days of useless attempts.

First let me tell you the following discover in my attemps:

If during installation, I DO NOT add plugins ( manual select plugins and then select None ), The User creation WILL WORK.
HOWEVER as soon as I start adding necessary plugins later (like "git" for example or many others) the problem reappears.

Anyway **the solution** for me was to add a proper email in the last requested field.
Also remember to use only alphanumeric.

If this still does not work there is a sure workaround:
from command line go to Jenkins/Home/users.
copy your admin user (  cp -a admin your_new_user )
restart jenkins
Your new user is created, change from jenkins its credential.